# How can I adjust my NodeJs server code to responf to HTTPS requests?

Tags: node.js, https, server

I have a small nodejs server which is working without a problem. Now I am trying to make use of "HTTPS" for security reasons. I have the following code, but when I try to open the page in Firefox via link [`http://192.168.2.22:8080/api/users`], on the terminal I see **DIRECTING >>> https://192.168.2.22:8080/api/users** but in the browser, instead of the expected response, I encounter this error:

> Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to
>   192.168.2.22:8080. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

```
// Modules /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const db = require('./db.js');

// Packages ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const colors = require('colors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const fs = require('fs');

// Constant Variables //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const PORT_SERVER = 8080;
const HOST = '192.168.2.22';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
// app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));

// set up a route to redirect http to https
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('DIRECTING >>> https ://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
});

app.get('/api/users/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('CHECK POINT !!!');
    let users = await db.db.get_users();
    console.log("USERS : " + users);
    res.send(users);
});

// have it listen on 8080
app.listen(PORT_SERVER, () => console.log(`Listen at ${PORT_SERVER}...`));
```

How can I resolve this? I could not find a solution that I can easily apply to my code, **I am kind of a newbie for NodeJs**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the ssl setup on your server? you need to have a SSL certificate installed to use https!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not configured your server for SSL. Configure SSL using the https module like below. In this example, I have created two express one for Http and one for https as we can not run both http and non https on same port.

```
 const express = require('express');
 const   http = require('http'),
 const    https = require('https')
 const fs = require('fs')
 const httpApp = express()
 const app = express()

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("server.crt")
};
httpApp.set('port',80);
httpApp.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + "/" + req.path);
});

app.set('port', 443);
app.enable('trust proxy');

http.createServer(httpApp).listen(httpApp.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express HTTP server listening on port ' + httpApp.get('port'));
});

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express HTTPS server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

> **The Best way to redirect from non-http to https is to use Nginx web server as a reverse proxy and define redirection rule in Nginx config file.**
>
> **client--->nginx reverse proxy(with SSL and redirection rules)-->express server**

Answer (score -1):

try changing the port to 443, https runs on 443 by default!

Comment: You need an actual https server that is properly configured with certificates, not an http server to run https.  Yes, that will run on port 443, but you can't just change the port on a plain http server and expect that to run https.